# Splitting an Entity Framework linq query causes includes to not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

If I do this:

```
var shipmentQuery = dataAccess.Shipments().Where(x => x.OriginId == originId)
    .Take(100)
    .Include(shipment => shipment.Boxes);

return shipmentQuery;
```

My box data is included in the result set.  But if I do this:

```
var shipmentQuery = dataAccess.Shipments().Where(x => x.OriginId == originId);

shipmentQuery
    .Take(100)
    .Include(shipment => shipment.Boxes);
```

Then the box data is not included (boxes is null for every result.)

**Are includes supposed to not work if you break up the query?**

And, is there anyway to be able to break it up?  (I want to add a few conditional where clauses.)

(I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 connecting to a sql server 2012 database.)

Comment: Hello, i think in the first query your telling the DbContext to get the Boxes data as well but on the second one your just simply telling the DbContext to get the Shipments data.

Comment: You can check as well the count of the first query and the second query. I bet the first one will be 100 and the other will be more than 100, if you have Shipments data more than 100.

Comment: In your second example the `Take().Include()` part does nothing because you don't use/assign the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the include statement with the first statement. It won't actually query the db at that point, it's just a query definition, so you don't have to worry about extra records being pulled.

Something like this:

```
var shipmentQuery = dataAccess.Shipments().Where(x => x.OriginId == originId)
    .Include(shipment => shipment.Boxes);

// Extra query conditions can be applied here

return shipmentQuery.Take(100);
```